# c program red-black-tree insert memory leaks (core dumped) and other issues

Tags: c, red-black-tree

I'm working on a red black tree assignment for my class and I'm having some trouble with the insertion function. My problem is that get memory leaks when i try to add more than tree nodes. so i need help with fixing this implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int key;
    char color;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
}Node;

Node *tree = NULL;

Node *createNode(int key) {
    Node *temp;
    temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->color = 'R';
    return temp;
}


Node* rightRotate(Node *root,Node *x)
{
    Node *y;
    y = x->right;  
    x->right = y->left;// zamienia lewe podrzewo y w prawe poddrzewo x
    if( y->left != NULL){
        y->left->parent = x; 
    }
    y->parent = x->parent; //łaczy starego ojca x i ojca y
    if( x->parent == NULL){
        root= y;
    }
    else if( x->key == x->parent->left->key){
        x->parent->left = y; 
    }    
    else 
        x->parent->right = y;
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y; 
    return root;
}

Node* leftRotate(Node *root,Node *y)
{
    Node *x;
    x = y->left; 
    y->left = x->right; 
    if ( x->right != NULL)
    {
        x->right->parent = y;
    }
    x->parent = y->parent; 
    if( y->parent == NULL)
    { 
        root = x;
    } 
    else if( y->key == y->parent->left->key)
    {
        y->parent->left = x; 
    }
    else
        y->parent->right = x;
    x->right = y; 
    y->parent = x; 
    return root;
}


Node *insertBST(Node *root,Node *temp)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        return temp;
    }
    if (temp->key < root->key) {
        root->left = insertBST(root->left, temp);
        root->left->parent= root;
    }
    else if (temp->key > root->key) {
        root->right = insertBST(root->right, temp);
        root->right->parent = root;
    }
    return root;
}


Node* fixRBT(Node *root, Node *z) {
    Node *y;
    while ( z!= root  && z->parent->color == 'R')
    {
        if (z->parent->key == z->parent->parent->left->key)
        {
            y = z->parent->parent->right;
            if (y->color == 'R')
            { 
                z->parent->color = 'B';
                y->color = 'B';
                z->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                z = z->parent->parent;
            }
            else if (z->key == z->parent->right->key)
            {
                z = z->parent;
                root = leftRotate(root,z);
            }
            z->parent->color = 'B';
            z->parent->parent->color = 'R';
            root=rightRotate(root,z->parent->parent);
        }
        else {
            y = z->parent->parent->left;
            if (y->color == 'R') {
                z->parent->color = 'B';
                y->color = 'B';
                z->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                z = z->parent->parent;
            }
            else if (z->key == z->parent->left->key)
            {
                z = z->parent;
                root=rightRotate(root,z);
            }
            z->parent->color = 'B';
            z->parent->parent->color = 'R';
            root=leftRotate(root,z->parent->parent);
        }
    }
    root->color = 'B';
    return root;
}

void insert(int key) {
    Node *temp = createNode(key);
    tree = insertBST(tree, temp);
    tree=fixRBT(tree, temp);
}

void inorder(struct Node* root)
{
    struct Node* temp = root;
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        inorder(temp->left);
        printf(" %d-%c ",temp->key,temp->color);
        inorder(temp->right);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    insert(38);
    insert(31);
    insert(39);
    inorder(tree);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: valgrind is your friend

Comment: how do you know you have memory leaks?

Comment: reading through this code. The first insert calls insertBST - this does nothing since tree (the root) is NULL. fixRBT then inspects node->parent->color. parent has never been set.